# Lambda expression with list operations

Tags: python

Shouldn't the below lambda expression return a list? Currently, it isn't.

```
 >>> f=lambda l ,x:l.append(x) 
 >>> print f([1],3)
 None
```

Comment: Why? There is no `return` and `l.append` does not return a list.

Comment: @LutzHorn: Lack of a `return` doesn't matter (`lambda`s return the result of the expression evaluated implicitly), but yeah, `list.append` returns `None` (the default return for functions that don't return something explicitly), which means it won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) is a side-effecting function; it appends a value to an existing list without returning a value (or None, depending on how you want to think of it).

Perhaps you want:

```
lambda l, x: l + [x]
```

This creates a new list from the existing list with an element appended at the end.

Comment: But by default lambda is suppose to return a value explicitly right? List in this case

Comment: There's nothing magical about a lambda, its value is the value of its body - `None` in this case.

Comment: No, it implicitly returns returns statement result. Result of `list.append` is `None`, so it returns `None`.

Comment: A function without a return value i.e. `def foo(): pass` or `def foo(): return` automatically returns None. f returns what append returns, which is `None`

Answer (score 0):

the function `append` returns `None` so your lambda returns `None`, too. Also the `append` changes the local variable `l` only

Comment: It "doesn't return anything" is wrong. **`None` is not nothing**. Use `print(type(None))`  to see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

[`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) does not return a value but because the python list is a [mutable object](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/), `3` will indeed be appended, it just doesn't get returned.

For example this will work:

```
t = [1]
f(t, 3)
print(t)        # [1, 3]
```

If you do not want to modify `t` you can write

```
f = lambda l, x: l + [x]

t = [1]

print(f(t, 3))  # [1, 3]
print(t)        # [1]
```

as the lambda will not modify the list `t` but just return a new list.